# Visual Studio Debugger freezes on XDocument query

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, vsto, linq-to-xml

I am having issues with the Visual Studio 2022 debugger whilst implementing a VSTO PPT addin. However, in the built version the VSTO Addin works just fine and does not crash.

My code:

```
var config = Configuration; //Configuration is an XDocument
var query = config.Root.Elements("MyElement");
```

If I remove the second line the debugger works just fine, but obviously I need to read the XML message.

```
var config = Configuration; //Configuration is an XDocument
//var query = config.Root.Elements("MyElement");
```

snippet of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddinConfig>
  <PPTConfig>
    <MyElement>true</MyElement>
  </PPTConfig>
  <XLSConfig />
</AddinConfig>
```

Comment: Does it freeze or does it crash? If you don't already have exception handling around that code, put some in and then look at the Exception.

Comment: have you tried with a different xml?

Comment: BTW, that code will not find "MyElement" but that is not the reason for a crash or freeze. You could use `config.Descendants("MyElement")`

Comment: How is it related to VSTO add-ins? I suppose it doesn't matter what kind of applications you develop, right?